# Why `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of null` even with constructor?

Tags: reactjs

In Reactjs, if I have distructing assignment in `redner()` method like `const {foo} = this.state`, I'll get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'foo' of null` if `this.state` hasn't been defined or initialized. This make sense. However, what doesn't make sense is that, even if I have `constructor()` method to initialize `this.state`, I'm still getting the error. Apparently `render()` is called BEFORE `constructor()`.

Of course I can always check if `this.state === null` to avoid the error. But getting this error doesn't make sense to me. It seems that `constructor` is not being processed properly. Why call it constructor if it's not being called first? What would be the proper way to ensure `state` is defined when it's referred in `render()`?

Code for reference.

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';

export default class Objective extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      foo: 'bar',
    };
  }

  render() {
    const {foo} = this.state; // <-- getting Uncaught TypeError!
    return (<div>{foo}</div>);
  }
}
```

Comment: Your code works fine https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/39166/ something else is happening. What environment are you running it in? Are you using Babel with presets?

Comment: you should use babel to support

Comment: Just tried it again and the error was gone. It's really weird. Maybe has something to do with my webpack dev tool configuration.